# A 3 column CSS solution expanded on the whole width of the page

Tags: html, css

I would like a full-width 3 columns like showed below

[image]

So:

SideL (left column) width: 150px

Content (center column) width: auto

SideR (right column) width: 250px

Here is what I have (CSS):

```
div#SideL   { float: left; width: 150px; }
div#Content { float: left; width: 70%; }
div#SideR   { float: left; width: 250px; }
```

**The problem is in the Content where I had to set a width of 70%. This is not what I was looking for. I would prefer something like: width:auto but it doesn't work.** >> I would like the content width to expand on the whole width of the page.

Any idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need all columns to have the same height too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use absolute positions. Check the following css:

```
div#SideL   {position:absolute;width:150px;}
div#Content {position:absolute;left:151px;right:251px;}
div#SideR   {position:absolute;right:0;width:250px; }
```

Using `left` and `right` for `div#Content` you can move the element wherever you wish

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/7radp/

Answer (score 2):

The third column is the actual middle column / filler, like:

```
<div  style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 150px; float: left;">
        1
    </div>
    <div style="width: 250px; float: right;">
        2
    </div>
    <div style="width: auto; margin-left: 150px; margin-right: 250px;">
       3
     </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>3 columns</title>
 <style type="text/css">

 #contentwrapper{
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 }

 #contentcolumn{
 margin: 0 250px 0 150px; /*Margins for content column. Should be "0 RightColumnWidth    0 LeftColumnWidth*/
 }

 #leftcolumn{
 float: left;
 width: 150px; /*Width of left column in percentage*/
 margin-left: -100%;
 background: #C8FC98;
 }

 #rightcolumn{
 float: left;
 width: 250px; /*Width of right column in pixels*/
 margin-left: -250px; /*Set margin to that of -(RightColumnWidth)*/
 background: #FDE95E;
 }

 </style>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="maincontainer">

 <div id="contentwrapper">
 <div id="contentcolumn">
 <div class="innertube">Content Column:</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div id="leftcolumn">
     Left Column
 </div>

 <div id="rightcolumn">
     Right Column
 </div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```